# How to flatten a list of strings containing parenthesis into a single list?

Tags: c++, qt

How can I parse this string list into a single list containing just the extensions as seen in the example below? I'm using Qt / C++

list to parse:

```
QStringList = [
     "Image files (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)",
     "Text files (*.txt)",
     "Any files (*)"
];
```

wanted result:

`QStringList = ["*.png", "*.xpm", "*.jpg", "*.txt", "*"]`

Comment: It's very simple. It happens to be exactly the same way that you get by taking out a blank sheet of paper, writing down a sequence of brief, logical sentences in plain English that describe the algorithm that does this, and then by having this [reviewed and approved by your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Have you yet tried discussing your proposed course of action with your rubber duck, yet, and if not why not? What is your specific question about C++? "Please write some code that does this" is not a specific C++ question.

Comment: It's a parsing problem. You can read up lots of theory on how to write parsers (which would be well worth while) but in this case I think you just need a regex. Read up on those instead.

Comment: May I ask you to have a look at the solution I have provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

For each element of the QStringList get the content between parentheses and the split it:

```
QStringList stringList = ["Image files (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)","Text files (*.txt)","Any files (*)"];
QStringList newStringList = [];
for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++){

    //Get the parentheses
    string element= stringlist.at(i);
    unsigned first = element.find("(");
    unsigned last = element.find(")");
    first++;
    string extensions = element.substr (first,last-first);

    //Split it with the " " as delimiter.
    size_t pos = 0;
    string extension;
    string delimiter = " ";
    while ((pos = extensions.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
         extension= s.substr(0, pos);
         //Add here extension to your new qstringlist
         newStringList.append(extension);
         std::cout << extension<< std::endl;
         extensions.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
*.png
*.xmp
*.jpg
*.txt
*
```

Hope it works for you!

Comment: This does not even compile.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

The Qt way would be to use the functionality provided by [QString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) in order to remove the text outside of the brackets, including the brackets themselves, splitting the rest of the text into space separated segments like this:

```
foreach (const QString &str, fileTypes)
    extensions.append(str.split("(").last().chopped(1).split(" "));
```

where `fileTypes` and `extensions` are the input and output string lists respectively.

## Example

Here is a working example I have written for you to be able to test the proposed solution:

```
#include <QDebug>

int main(int /*argc*/, char /**argv[]*/)
{
    QStringList fileTypes({
        "Image files (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)",
        "Text files (*.txt)",
        "Any files (*)"
    });
    QStringList extensions;

    foreach (const QString &str, fileTypes)
        extensions.append(str.split("(").last().chopped(1).split(" "));

    qDebug() << extensions;

    return 0;
}
```

## Result

As written, the given example produces the following result:

```
("*.png", "*.xpm", "*.jpg", "*.txt", "*")
```

Comment: @JokerMartini, please take a moment to have a look at this solution.